# opencv, C++, как отсортировать вектор vector <vector<Point>>

Tags: c++, opencv

Есть вектор векторов точек `vector <vector<Point>>`
Нужно перенести часть векторов из него в другой, такой же вектор.
Делал так:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int i, q, z;            //для счетчиков

Mat src_edge = imread("C:\\1/edge.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);      //ПОПРАВИТЬ ЭТУ СТРОКУ


int main()
{
    Mat layer_edge[3];                  //3 слоя - B, G, R, нам нужен [1] - green
    split(src_edge, layer_edge);

    Mat mask_edge[3];

    for (q = 0; q < 3; q++)
    {
        adaptiveThreshold(layer_edge[q], mask_edge[q], 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, THRESH_BINARY, 19, false);      //3 слоя маски, потом нам будет нужна только одна
    }
    vector <vector<Point>> contours_src;        //сырые векторы
    vector <vector<Point>> contours_good;       //хорошие векторы

    findContours(mask_edge[1], contours_src, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    std::cout << "\n\n size(contours_src) = " << size(contours_src) << "\n\n";

    //сортируем контуры по площади, (20...100)
    double cont_area;
    z = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size(contours_src); i++)
    {
        cont_area = contourArea(contours_src[i]);

        if (cont_area < 20 || cont_area > 100)
        {}
        else
        {
//          contours_good[z] = contours_src[i];   //ОШИБКА
            contours_good.push_back(contours_src[i]);  //работает, спасибо AR Hovsepyan-у
            z++;
        }
    }
    waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

и через итератор делал;
и .at пробовал и .push_back;
Все равно вываливается ошибка - Debag Assertion Faled.

Я новичок, месяц программирую, и еще не умею копать debugger-ы, но, в чем ошибка?
[image: уже обработанный край объекта для распознания]

Comment: Приведите более полный код. По этому отрезку сложно что-то сказать.

Comment: у contours_good нет элементов, а вы пытаетесь их присваивать. Вместо присваивания  contours_good[z] = contours_src[i];  положите в конец:  contours.push_back( contours_src[i]); И уберите лишные объекты

Comment: &AR Hovsepyan
Спасибо! Наверное, я что-то напутал с синтаксисом, когда говорил, что пробовал push_back

Answer (score 0):

contours_good.push_back(contours_src[i]);  //правильный ответ
//AR Hovsepyan`а